# App does not update textfield from settings bundle but it does update settings from the app

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

Hi if i change the required field in the application, then log out and log into settings, the settings have been updated perfectly. 
However if i then proceed to change the settings and then open the application once more the textfield has not changed.

how do i get the textfield to automatically update from the settings bundle and not just one way

this is the code i am using in the view did load

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.textField1.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: In this case you need to call `[defaults synchronize]` *before* you populate the text field.

Comment: Didn't work, i seem to be able to only change the settings from the app itself, not the other way around.

Comment: how are you updating inside the app?

Comment: within the textfielddidendediting

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:textField.text forKey:@"user_name"];

Comment: turns out if i put it in the textfielddidbeginediting method
 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
 
self.textField1.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_name"];
then as soon as someone clicks it updates to what i want, however i really need it to update as soon as the app loads.

Comment: answered     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(updateMytex:)
name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
object:nil];
 

I used notification center to call my updateMytex method,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateMytex:)     name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

I used notification center to call my `updateMytex` method.

Comment: Utlized notification to fire up uiApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotificion from the delegate, this is called whenever the app is brought into the foreground, i then set the selector to a method i implemented in my own class file called updateMyTex, this method updated the required textfield.